# How can I cast class for my object for PHP?

Tags: php, class, object

I have object $obj (class A). 
Can I convert class for $obj to B?
Perhaps there is another way.

Example:

```
class A 
{
    public $AProp = 1;
    public function &Convert($ATypeName)
    {
       // HOW?
       return $this;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
   public $BProp = 2;
}

$obj=new A();
$obj->Convert("B");

print_r($obj->BProp);
```

I wrote next solution, but it is no good.
(It looks like your post is mostly code; I add some more details)

```
class A 
{
   public $AProp = 1;
   public function &Convert($ATypeName)
   {
       $Result = new $ATypeName; // Create new object
       $Result->AProp = $this->AProp; // Copy params...
       return $Result; 
   }
}

class B extends A
{
   public $BProp = 2;
}


$obj = new A();
$obj->AProp = 3;
$obj = $obj->Convert("B");

print_r($obj);
```

Comment: what do you mean by convert ? do you want that `$obj` become a class B and erase all the properties of class A, become a class B and keep all the properties of class A or  stay a class A and keep his properties and add the ones of the class B to the class A ?

Comment: In the beginning, I create the main object (class A) with the main functions. I work with him. Sometimes I need extended functions in from class (B). In that moment i want convert class of object from A to B.

Comment: Converting objects of type A to type B does not make sense - if you tried this with real world classes rather than abstract ones you will soon find out trying to force one object to one of it's derived classes means you don't have all the information you may need.  If the two classes were truly interchangeable as you want - they should be the same class (IMHO)

Comment: Oh no. I constructed classes for extended functions and sources files (*.php). You do not worry about different classes.

Comment: Please add more information to the question itself, not to the comment section

Answer (score 0):

u are trying to use c++-way of class extending.
the php-way is smth like this:

```
<?php
class A 
{
    protected $prop = 1;
    public function getProp()
    {
       return $this->prop;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
   protected $prop = 2;
}

$obj=new A();
print_r($obj->getProp());

$obj=new B();
print_r($obj->getProp());
```

also take a look on late static bindings - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

```
<?php
class A 
{
    public static $prop = 1;
    public function getProp()
    {
       return static::$prop;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
   public static $prop = 2;
}

$obj=new A();
print_r($obj->getProp());

$obj=new B();
print_r($obj->getProp());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way:

```
$obj = new B();
```

Since inheritance is used you can access all class `A` func and var, like `$this->Aprop`

Comment: Are you sure about this? `new B()` creates a **new** instance, and does not convert or cast anything

Comment: Yes, it is. Do you know another way? I asked about this.